# header text going on two lines

Tags: html, asp.net, css, gridview

I have a gridview in which one of my column's header text is going on two lines, which look very ugly,

I added item width and header width but no good,

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="userID" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="User ID But Only ID" HeaderStyle-Width="300px"
            ItemStyle-Width="300px" />
```

Anyone guide me to right direction as I want   `User ID But Only ID`   in 1 line in header

Comment: plz show your `Grid View` code..

Comment: Rahul, i am following this tutorial http://www.ashishblog.com/blog/nested-gridview-in-showhide-effect-using-c-net/

Comment: i think your `header text` is to long that does not fit on total width of `Grid View`..

Comment: how can i force this header to be on one line, forgetting everything else

Comment: try to set `HeaderStyle-Width` of other header as well as per the total width of `Grid View`.

Comment: i fixed problem by removing "spaces" with "&nbsp;"